# mvc 4 - javascript button stop working after enter text

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I read a lot of posts that looked similar to this issue, but none of them helped me. I have this button that adds text to a textarea. However, if i enter text manually in the textarea, the button stops do work. What am i doing wrong?

Model:

```
public class WhateverModels
{
    public string TheText { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public class WhateverController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SelectList tokens = new SelectList(new string[] { "A", "B", "C" });
        this.ViewBag.tokens = tokens;
        WhateverModels w = new WhateverModels();
        return View(w);
    }
 }
```

View:

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%: Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.TheText) %>
    <br />
    <%: Html.DropDownList("tokens", string.Empty)%>
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="AddButton" onclick="addToken()">test</button>
    <script>
        function addToken() {
            var combo = document.getElementById("tokens");
            document.getElementById("TheText").textContent =
                document.getElementById("TheText").textContent +
                "[" + combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value + "]";
        }
    </script>
 </asp:Content>
```

Step by step:

1) Open the page

2) Click test button (note that the text is added to the textarea)

3) Enter the textarea and type something

4) Click test button (now it does not work)

(using firefox)

Thanks for your attention

Comment: It's will not solve your problem, but look at [+= operator MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators). `document.getElementById("TheText").textContent += "[" + combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value + "]";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textContent attribute is not well supported in some browsers.  It is better to use textArea.value for setting text:

```
            function addToken() {
                var combo = document.getElementById("tokens");
                document.getElementById("TheText").value +=
                "[" + combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value + "]";
            }
```

For some reason on FF and Chrome setting textContent does not update the UI.

Comment: It worked, thank you! The VS2013 intellisense did not show the "value" attribute, but it worked anyway at runtime.